# PHP Session Timer Works Initially but Gone Wrong

Tags: php, session, timer, countdowntimer

So I have a php session timer that works but somehow gets bugged out after awhile... this is the code and the console log I got. I'm looking for a fix to this problem, or possibly a different set of code to achieve the same timer effect *(as I'm not sure if using session is the best method for a timer)*

```
session_start();
function timer($time) {
        //Set the countdown to 120 seconds.
    $_SESSION['countdown'] = $time*60;
        //Store the timestamp of when the countdown began.
    $_SESSION['time_started'] = time();

    $now = time();
    $timeSince = $now - $_SESSION['time_started'];
    $remainingSeconds = abs($_SESSION['countdown'] - $timeSince);
    $counter = 0; 

    $minutes = $remainingSeconds/60;
    echo "$minutes minutes countdown starts.".PHP_EOL;
    while($remainingSeconds >= 1) {
        $now = time();
        $timeSince = $now - $_SESSION['time_started'];

        if (($timeSince-$counter) >= 60) {
            $remainingSeconds = abs($_SESSION['countdown'] - $timeSince);
            $counter = $timeSince;
            $minutes = $remainingSeconds/60;
            echo "$minutes minutes has passed.".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if($remainingSeconds < 1){
        session_abort(); 
        return true;
    }
}

if($this->timer(30)) {
        // do whatever
        echo "$time has passed";
    }
```

Here's what happens in the console:

```
30 minutes countdown starts.
29 minutes has passed.
.... (continue as per pattern)
16 minutes has passed.
15 minutes has passed. (problem occurs here)
8.7166666666667 minutes has passed.
7.7166666666667 minutes has passed.
6.7166666666667 minutes has passed.
.... (continue as per pattern)
0.71666666666667 minutes has passed.
0.28333333333333 minutes has passed.
1.2833333333333 minutes has passed.
2.2833333333333 minutes has passed.
.... (continue as per pattern all the way)
```

Extra notes: The session timer doesn't always recur this same pattern, there have been times when it ran through the entire 30minutes and managed to **echo "$time has passed";** while the bug only occured later on

Comment: Every time you call timer() you set  $_SESSION['time_started'] = time(); That seems to mess up things.
Try to separate the code. Do something like a timer_init() function and a timer_check() function and only set the variables in the timer_init() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't run your, but just from reading it I think there are a few things very wrong with it.

1. Sessions. You're not using them right.

Session values should only be set once, meaning before you do `$_SESSION['countdown'] = $time*60;` and `$_SESSION['time_started'] = time();`, you should check if they already exist or not, and only assign if nonexistent. Your current code resets the clock every time the page is refreshed, which defeats the purpose of sessions.

2. `abs`. I think you're not using them right either.

You shouldn't abs the remaining seconds all the time. `$remainingSeconds = abs($_SESSION['countdown'] - $timeSince);` should be allowed to go into negative. Negative remaining seconds mean your timeout has expired / you've missed it! Calling `abs` means you're effectively letting it go forever if you by any chance miss the exact time of your event. **This is the answer to your main problem**. Fix this and your counter will stop going to zero and back up again.

3. You're relying on your code correctly checking every single second. But it doesn't.

The nasty decimals you're getting happen when for some reason your code gets delayed and doesn't correctly check the 60th second, which means your division by 60 is not perfectly round and you get 8.7166666 minutes.

If you start by removing the `abs` calls and generally try to simplify your code a bit, I believe you'll quickly get it to work as intended.

**// Edit 1**

This is a very naive, but simplified approach to your problem. I left two different outputs in there for you to pick one.

```
function timer($time) {
    echo "$time minutes countdown starts." . PHP_EOL;

    // Save the date in future when the timer should stop
    $endTime = time() + $time * 60;

    // Keeps track of last full minute to simplify logs
    $lastFullMinute = $time;

    while(true) {
        $timeRemaining = $endTime - time();

        if ($timeRemaining <= 0) {
            // Time remaining is less than zero, which means we've gone beyond the end date.
            // End the loop
            return;
        }

        // Round up!
        $minutesRemaining = ceil($timeRemaining / 60);
        if ($minutesRemaining != $lastFullMinute) {
            // Current "minute" is different than the previous one, so display a nice message

            // If you want to show how many minutes are remainig, use this:
            echo "$minutesRemaining minutes remaining." . PHP_EOL;

            // If you want to show how many minutes have passed, you have to take mintutesRemaining away from the original time
            $minutesPassed = $time - $minutesRemaining;
            echo "$minutesPassed minutes passed." . PHP_EOL;

            $lastFullMinute = $minutesRemaining;
        }
    }
}
```

The main way for you to improve it further would be to use the `sleep` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php. Currently the `while loop` will hog all the CPU by constantly checking if the timer happened, so you should sleep for a few seconds inside.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, for
point 1. Why I reset the clock every time, is because I'm trying to make a countdown timer, and so I need to reset it as per $time every time I call the function

point 2. I'll test out the abs and get back to you, but I do not fully understand the negative part so I'll prolly have to read up on that

point 3. Not fully sure what else you mean by simplify but I'll try my best. Thanks for the excellent explanation :)

Comment: Imagine a 1 minute timer (60s). If time remaining equals `-10`, it means that 70 second have passed since the timer started. Meaning you should have "stopped" your scripts 10s ago. In your code this never happens, because `-10` is treated as `+10`, suggesting that you still have `10`, then `+20`, then `+30`s left an so your script goes forever. Does it make sense?

Comment: ohh so since my conditional was 
    if (($timeSince-$counter) >= 60) {}

Comment: and `$remainingSeconds = abs($_SESSION['countdown'] - $timeSince);` so if `$timesince > $_SESSION['countdown']` by even 1 second it will cause that error yea?

Comment: Indeed :) Try restructuring your code based on the assumption that `$remainingSeconds` **can** be negative, and you'll see how much you can simplify. Also as per your first comment, if you don't want the timer to be persistent, then you might as well remove sessions altogether and use normal variables.

Comment: oh, but how would I refresh and make sure `1 second` has passed? Other than that,  would it be possible to use `while($dateTimeVar1 < $dateTimevar2) {} ` ?

Comment: I'm using sessions timer as I found this code from online, and just manipulated it to my own use of a countdown timer haha, I'm not very good with coding still and am still slowly improving, thanks for the help tho, I'm running my code now and its a 2hour cycle so I have to leave it for awhile before I know whether it works fully

Comment: Added a small example inspired by your code. The `DateTime` solution you've posted is "ok", but also incredibly messy and over complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, for the sleep function, what would be a good time? 10-30 seconds?? Or is it possible to extend to many minutes

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using DateTime for this at all. And the sleep duration... either use some small amount like you said  `10-20` seconds or do it "properly" and calculate how many seconds remain until the next full minute :) But that's another question. Good luck with this!

Comment: Yeap, when you say to do it "properly" as in to just keep running the code w/o sleep? But thats not recommended due to CPU issues as you said right?

Comment: Could you help me check the below solution then? Thats the shortest I can think of from what you've written

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this solution? referenced from above

```
function timer($time) {
echo "$time minutes countdown starts." . PHP_EOL;

// Save the date in future when the timer should stop
$endTime = time() + $time*60;

while(true) {
    sleep(20);
    $secondsRemaining = $endTime - time();

    if ($secondsRemaining <= 0) {
        echo 'Finished';
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems correct. You don't even need to return "true" from it. Just a plain return will suffice because there is no way for the function to return false or otherwise.

Comment: If you don't need any output, you can get even shorter `function timer($time) { sleep($time*60); } `. All the other code was to allow "pretty print" of log messages as the timer progresses.

Comment: yea I thought of that, but I'm not sure the reliability of the sleep function of sorts haha or whether its a best practice thing

Comment: From personal experience sleep is relatively accurate. Within reason of course and even 5s difference will be better than a fully blocked CPU.